# external keyboard to behave in OSX as it would do in Windows

Tags: keyboard-layout, osx-yosemite, remapping

I'm struggling to configure under OSX Yosemite a [Logitech K270 wireless keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkKAE.png) to behave the same as it would do under Windows. The keyboard is paired to a mid 2015 15" MacBook Pro.

What I desperately need:

1. Insert, Home, PageUp, Delete, End, PageDown (upper-mid section). These buttons should work **EXACTLY** as they do under Windows.
2. When NumLock is off, Home, PageUp, End, PageDown, Ins, Del and the arrow keys on the numeric keypad should work **EXACTLY** as they do under Windows.
3. Alt-shift **MUST** change keyboard layout (I frequently change between US and Hungarian).

I tried Karabiner but the functionality is erratic and highly dependent on the software I use. I need a consistent solution working across programs, irrespective whether these are local, remote or under a virtual machine.